# Ассемблерная команда LEA

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Не знаю почему, но эта ассемблерная команда не дает мне покоя `LEA`.

C++

```
int f(int t)
{
  return t+1;
}

int f(int*t)
{ 
  return *t+1;
}

int f(int& t)
{
  return t+1;
}
```

Ассемблер

```
f(int):                                  # @f(int)
        lea     eax, [rdi + 1]
        ret

f(int*):                                 # @f(int*)
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        inc     eax
        ret

f(int&):                                 # @f(int&)
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        inc     eax
        ret
```

Если команда `MOV` ясна как день, то команда `LEA` не ясна!

Я знаю что команда `LEA` выполняет вычисление адреса второго операнда и записывание его в первый операнд (это все что мне известно)

В том примере что по ссылке, а именно:  `lea eax,[rdi + 1]` это явно не вычисление адреса и не запись в первый операнд, нет запись то будет но скорее всего что-то другое. Или я что-то не правильно понял? Объясните пожалуйста в соответствии с С++ кодом.

P.S Искал, но исчерпывающего ответа на мой вопрос не нашел, искал даже в книжке Калашникова, а там даже этой команды не нашел...эхх.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51310/discussion-on-question-by-maximpro---lea).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
lea eax, [rdi+1]
```

Эта команда загружает в `eax` адрес значения, лежащего по адресу rdi + 1. Т.е. она загружает в `eax` просто `rdi+1`.

Выглядит странно, и чтобы понять зачем именно нужна `lea`, и чем она лучше просто аналогичного вызова `mov` или ручного вычисления адреса, нужно понять как команды записываются в памяти и выполняются процессором.

Например, у вас есть команда чтения значения:

```
mov  eax, [rdi+1]; взять значение по адресу "rdi + 1"
```

Она компилируется в что-то вроде

```
[опкод mov][флаг что складываем в eax][флаг что берем по адресу rdi][+1]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. в `66 67 8B 47 01`

Предположим что вам нужно получить сам адрес `rdi+1` в `eax`

Вы можете сделать одно из двух:

Высчитать его руками:

```
mov eax, rdi + 1; не работает, move не умеет плюс!
```

и вам придется написать:

```
mov eax, rdi 
inc eax; 66 05 01 00 00 00
```

т.е. выполнить две инструкции. Возможно, хороший вариант, но только для простых +1. А для адресов вида `[bp+si+4]`?

```
mov eax, bp
add eax, si
add eax, 4; да, некрасиво!
```

или выполнить `lea`:

```
lea  eax, [rdi+1]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сравните с `mov`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Байткод: `66 67 8D 47 01`

Отличается *только opcode*, 8B -> 8D.

В процессоре есть готовый, очень эффективный механизм для базовых операций с адресами. И он уже реализован для операции `mov` - ведь `mov` умеет доставать значение по адресу!.

При использовании `lea` процессор делает все, что делает при `mov`, но пропускает последний шаг - извлечение значения по адресу. Вместо этого он складывает в `eax` сам адрес. Это гораздо удобнее и быстрее чем считать вещи вроде `rdi + 1` отдельными командами.

---

Какое это отношение имеет к вашему примеру?

В вашем примере параметр лежит в `rdi`, а результат вы должны вернуть в `eax`. 
По-честному, компилятор должен был написать

```
mov eax, rdi; 66 A1 
add eax, 1; 66 05 01 00 00 00
```

Ну ок, для 1 можно использовать `inc`:

```
mov eax, rdi; 66 A1 
inc eax; 66 40
```

Но это все еще две команды. Процессор будет выполнять их по очереди.

Компилятор умный. Он знает, что процессор умеет складывать значения регистров с небольшими константами при обработке команды `lea`. И он вставляет *одну* команду, которая выдаст тот же результат.

```
lea     eax, [rdi + 1]
```

Неважно, что никакой адрес на самом деле никуда не загружается - главное что работать будет точно так же, и чуть быстрее - т.к. процессор вычисляет адреса в памяти быстрее, чем складывает числа :)

Comment: Я вот не понял эту фразу: `Эта команда загружает в eax адрес значения, лежащего под адресу rdi + 1. Т.е. она загружает в eax значение rdi+1.` Сначала вы написали что в `eax` помещается адрес, потом вы пишите что в `eax` помещается значение. Вводите в заблуждение

Comment: @MaximPro исправил

Comment: Как я понял LEA это команда предназначенная для оперирования с адресами, то есть по сути сама команда ничего кроме пересылки как MOV делать не умеет за исключением того что второй операнд имеет обязательные скобки, в этих скобках можно делать любые операции и все что сделано там перешлется в первый операнд. Если это так то я понял смысл команды LEA
P.S А то что команду LEA используют для того чтобы делать вычисления - трюк для уменьшения количества операций.

Comment: @MaximPro да, правильно. на самом деле скобки там ради того, чтобы команда выглядела похоже на mov, который делает те же вычисления, но еще и берет значение по получившемуся адресу. Т.е. это хак для схожести команд в коде.

Comment: да, ассемблер это хак ради хаков =)

Comment: @PashaPash  ,`что делает при mov, но пропускает последний шаг - извлечение значения по адресу.`А как команда mov извлекает по адресу ?

Answer (score 3):

Эта команда загружает в `eax` адрес того, что справа - т.е. `rdi+1`. Такой хитрый способ объединить

```
mov  eax, rdi
inc  eax
```

Т.е. в каком-то смысле в переводе на C++ это

```
&*(rdi+1)
```

:) Т.е. получение адреса объекта, находящегося по адресу `[rdi+1]`.

См., например, [тут](https://exelab.ru/faq/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80:_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_LEA).

Comment: Не понятно! Это каким таким образом мы получим результат вычислений? `return x+1` ?

Comment: Везде в ассемблерных листингах передаваемое значение - `rdi`. Просто во второй и третьей функции в `rdi` - указатель, а в первой - само значение `x`. Возвращаемое значение у всех функций - в регистре `eax`.

Comment: Да команда знать не знает, что она вычисляет... ей сказали - поместить в регистр eax эффективный адрес байта по адресу [rdi + 1],- она именно это и выполнит. Т.е. тупенько так поместит в eax инкрементированное значение rdi. Попробуй иным способом проделать это, уложившись в одну команду, да при этом не затронуть ни других регистров, ни памяти, ни флагов...

Comment: @Akina Да еще и - "Отличие lea от mov состоит в том, что используется механизм блока адресации процессора, а не арифметико-логического блока"...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51311/discussion-on-answer-by-harry---lea).

Answer (score 3):

Данная команда

```
    lea eax,[rdi + 1]
```

заносит в регистр `eax` значение `rdi + 1`, где в `rdi` хранится значение аргумента.

В двух остальных случаях, когда аргумент передается по ссылке или передается указатель на исходный аргумент, то регистр `rdi` содержит адрес аргумента.

```
    f(int*):                                 # @f(int*)
            mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
            inc     eax
            ret

    f(int&):                                 # @f(int&)
            mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
            inc     eax
            ret
```

Поэтому сначала в регистр `eax` заносится значение аргумента, используя тот адрес, который находится в `rdi`

```
            mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
```

а затем значение регистра `eax` увеличивается на 1.

```
            inc     eax
```

То есть различие между первым определением функции и двумя последующими состоит в том, что в первом случае регистр `rdi` содержит **копию значения аргумента**, тогда как в двух последних случаях регистр `rdi` **получает адрес исходного аргумента**.

Comment: Я немного поковырялся с эмулятором ассемблера и запутался в конец. Я попробовал создать именованную область памяти и записать туда значение. Потом воспользовался командой LEA и она мне выдала адрес моей области памяти. Но когда я попробовал вместо именованной области памяти использовать регистр то я получил значение регистра, а не адрес. Почему так? Что вообще происходит? Помогите разобраться
P.S Могу показать скриншоты, но мне кажется что лучше это сделать в чате