# команда lea в компиляторе gcc(gas)

Tags: ассемблер, gcc

Перед тем , как задать этот вопрос , я прочитал этот ответ - [Ассемблерная команда LEA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610242/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-lea.%D0%9D%D0%BE) я так и не смог понять,что будет делать эта команда

```
leal (%rax,%rdx),%ecx
```

К чему эти скобки,что происходит внутри них.Похоже ли это на 
`ivector4[ i ] = i *2;` ,
ассемблерный код которого выглядит так  `ivector4(%eax,%eax)`?
В чём суть той команды `lea` скобками и самих этих скобок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта команда заносит в регистр `%ecx` сумму значений из регистров `%rax` и `%rdx`:

```
ecx = rax + rdx
```

Выражение в скобках, является операндом адреса (аналог `[]` в Intel синтаксисе) и имеет общий вид:

```
segment:displacement(base_register, index_register, scale_factor)
```

Эквивалентное выражение в Intel синтаксисе:

```
segment:[base_register + displacement + index_register * scale_factor]
```

Любой из элементов выражения может отсутствовать, соответсвенно, в вашем примере присутствуют только `base_register` и `index_register`.

Answer (score 2):

Буду пояснять на Intel - синтаксисе.

`lea` позволяет вам вычислять сложные адреса, которые получаются в результате выполнения арифметических операций.

Например, у нас есть метка `message`, и мы хотим получить её адрес в `rax`. Первое, что приходит на ум, это `mov rax, message`.

А что, если мы хотим получить адрес четвёртого байта, начиная с этой метки? `mov rax,  message + 4` уже нельзя использовать. Нужно сначала  сделать `mov rax, message` и только потом `add rax, 4`, но c `lea` это можно уместить в одну команду :

```
lea rax, [message + 4]
```

Чтобы вы понимали, покажу разницу :

```
mov rax, [ message + rbx ] ; в регистре - содержимое первых 8 байт, начиная с адреса метки "message" + числа, которое находится в "rbx".

lea rax, [ message + rbx ] ; в регистре - адрес метки "message" + "rbx". Это одно и то же, что и "mov rax, message", а потом "add rax, rbx"
```

Короче говоря, на то и "**l**oad **e**ffective **a**ddress", чтобы одновременно и адрес ячейки в памяти находить, и много `mov`'ов не применять :)