# Как работает команда lea со смещениями в C++

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Объясните пожалуйста, как работает команда lea в tasm на таком примере:

```
RES equ 52
HED equ 16

proc    @allocx
    push    eax
    lea eax,[eax*4+HED+RES] ;vиetnм hlaviиky a rezervovanйho mнsta
    push    eax
    call    alloc
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    test    eax,eax
    jz  @@ret
    add eax,HED
    mov [eax-16],ecx
    mov [dword eax-12],0    ;inicializuj na nulu
    mov [dword eax-4],1
    mov [dword eax-8],0
@@ret:  ret
endp    @allocx
```

Вымазываемая функция на C++:

```
void *Alloc(int size)
{
    return operator new(size);
}
```

Структура с которой работает код:

```
struct Numx
{
    int
        alen, // Allocated data length (in Tint units)
        len;  // Used data length (in Tint units), 0 = zero, -1 = variable, -2 = fraction, -5 = range, -12 = matrix
    bool
        sgn;  // Sign, plus -- 0, minus -- 1
    int
        exp,  // Exponent (how many Tints has integer part)
        m,    // Mantissa (most significant digits are at the beginning)
        d,    // Divisor (a number by which another number is to be divided)
        reserved[12];
};
```

Мне не нужен перевод этой функции, мне нужно именно то как работает команда lea в этом случае

Comment: `lea eax,[eax*4+HED+RES]` почти равносильна `mov eax,eax*4+HED+RES` про отличия не могу достоверно обьяснить. Команда была предназначена для вычисления адреса структуры, но позже, её начали использовать, например для умножения на 4, или 5: `lea eax, [eax*4 + eax]`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610242/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-lea первая ссылка поисковика

Comment: @nick_n_a, “`lea eax,[eax*4+HED+RES]` почти равносильна `mov eax,eax*4+HED+RES`” - отличия такие, что через mov так не сделаешь. tasm и masm вообще это скорее всего воспримут как `mov eax,[eax*4+HED+RES]`. Лучше на псевдокоде написать, что `eax = eax*4+HED+RES`